# Verify Password in offline Xamarin Forms application

Tags: forms, authentication, xamarin

We have a Xamarin Forms application that works both connected and offline. The application connects to an API in our MVC Web application. This application uses Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication and the passwords are hashed in the User table. In connected mode, we call the API and get a jwt token back with no problems. For offline mode, we clone the user table in a local SQLite database. The question is, how do we verify the password against the local hashed password in offline mode when a user is logging in?

Thanks.

Comment: take user password and do hash and then compare those hash value

Comment: Thanks. How do I match the hash generated by Microsoft Authentication? I believe each hash is unique.

Comment: The hash created by MD5CryptoServiceProvider() does not provide the same results as Microsoft Authentication so you cannot compare the values.

Answer (score 0):

take user password and do hash and then compare those hash value 
ref :
https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/307020/how-to-compute-and-compare-hash-values-by-using-visual-c